# Can't append Base URL to create absolute links with Beatifulsoup Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I get a list of links in the output file but need all of the links to show as absolute links. Some are absolute and others are relative. How do I append the base url to the relatives to ensure that I get only absolute links in the csv output?

## I get back all the links but not all are absolute links e.g /subpage instead of http://page.com/subpage

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import requests 
    import csv

    j = requests.get("http://cnn.com").content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(j, "lxml") 
    
    #only return links to subpages e.g. a tag that contains href
    data = []
        for url in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
        print(url['href'])
        data.append(url['href'])
        
    print(data)
    
    with open("file.csv",'w') as csvfile:
    write = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter = ' ')
    write.writerows(data)

    content = open('file.csv', 'r').readlines()
    content_set = set(content)
    cleandata = open('file.csv', 'w')

    for line in content_set:
        cleandata.write(line)
```

Answer (score 2):

with `urljoin`:

```
from urlparse import urljoin
...
base_url = "http://cnn.com"
absolute_url = urljoin(base_url, relative_url)
```